# (Reopened) Please Re-Open "Disagreeing with company's code of conduct"

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[Disagreeing with company's code of conduct](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/184861/disagreeing-with-companys-code-of-conduct/184874?noredirect=1#comment605627_184874)

This was closed because it apparently "needs details or clarity."

This question does not actually need detail or clarity.

I think the OP has done a good job of trying to keep the question general enough so that:

1. The question is more useful to others with similar issues
2. The discussion doesn't get sidetracked to discuss the merits of the code of conduct.

People are asking specifically what the OP doesn't like about the code of conduct. The answer to that simply doesn't matter.

The question isn't asking if the code of conduct is reasonable. The question isn't asking if the OPs opinion is reasonable or not. Indeed, those would be difficult questions to answer without extra knowledge. We can simply accept that the OP has some sort of problem with the code of conduct and consider what the best course of action is.

I know reputation isn't everything, but let's look at the reputations of some of the people that HAVE managed to answer the question, I think succinctly:

- 346k
- 139k
- 94.5k

So, it's obvious that it can be answered.

Comment: Seems fine to me as well. I've reopened it. Haven't actually answered it myself as I have nothing to add.

Answer (score 1):

I ([fairly obviously](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/184861/disagreeing-with-companys-code-of-conduct/184863#184863)) agree this is/was answerable. While I can see an argument that there would be *better* answers if the OP were to provide more details such as their objections and, probably more importantly whether they intend to *comply* with the code (despite their objections).

I'm not sure I'm comfortable hammering it open myself - having an answer that is at the time of writing highly upvoted and accepted makes me concerned that I might not be entirely impartial if I did. But if it gets to  4 VTRO I'll happily cast the final one.